# Pass an argument to a gulp task when another task depends on it

Tags: node.js, gulp

Let's say I have something like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    argv = require("yargs").argv;

gulp.task("config", function (cb) {
    "use strict";

    if (argv.ftp) {
        console.log("Reading FTP settings...");
    } elseif (argv.sync) {
        console.log("Reading Sync settings..."):
    }
});

gulp.task("ftp", ["config"], function(cb) {
    console.log("FTPing...");
});

gulp.task("sync", ["config"], function(cb) {
    console.log("Syncing...");
});
```

Here's the idea:

- User runs `gulp ftp`, which relies on `gulp config`.
- `gulp-config` checks some values related to `ftp` in `config.json`, and prompts the user to enter anything that's missing.
- `gulp ftp` then carries on with it's task.

Alternatively,

- User runs `gulp sync`, which relies on `gulp config`.
- `gulp-config` checks some values related to `sync` in `config.json`, and prompts the user to enter anything that's missing.
- `gulp sync` then carries on with it's task.

I have this all working just fine, except in order to get the `config` task working correctly as a dependency of either `ftp` or `sync`, I have to run `gulp ftp --ftp` or `gulp sync --sync`. What I'd like to do is tell `gulp config` that if it's being run as a dependency of `gulp ftp`, assume the `--ftp` flag, and it's being run as a dependency of `gulp sync`, assume the `--sync` flag.

So my question is, is there a way to tell when a gulp task is the dependency of another? When `gulp-config` runs due to being a dependency of `gulp-ftp`, is there a way to check that at the start of `gulp-config`?

---

**UPDATE 1:** I had the idea to do something like `if (argv.ftp || config === "ftp")`, where `config` is a global variable that gets set in either the `ftp` or `sync` task, but I then realized that won't work because the variable wouldn't get set until after the `config` task finished. I'll continue researching...

Comment: I don't know the direct answer to your question, but I think your problem can be solved with some refactoring. Would you like to try? :)

Comment: Yea, I'm looking in to externalizing the two functions I use to write to the `config.json`, I feel like I might be on to something I'll continue updating as I make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is tell `gulp config` that if it's being run as a dependency of `gulp ftp`, assume the `--ftp` flag, and it's being run as a dependency of `gulp sync`, assume the `--sync` flag.

You can actually kind of do this, although I am hesitant to recommend it since it is not part of the officially documented Gulp API.

Gulp inherits its task running capabilities from [`orchestrator`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator) which stores the execution order of tasks in an array `seq`. Running `gulp ftp` on the command line would result in a `seq` array `['config', 'ftp']`.

So if `config` is run as a dependency of `ftp`, it will appear before `ftp` in the `seq` array. You can simply check for this condition in your `config` task:

```
gulp.task("config", function () {
  if (gulp.seq.indexOf('config') < gulp.seq.indexOf('ftp') || argv.ftp) {
    console.log("Reading FTP settings...");
  }
  if (gulp.seq.indexOf('config') < gulp.seq.indexOf('sync') || argv.sync) {
    console.log("Reading Sync settings...");
  }
});
```

**Another option** would be to check if `ftp` has been called on the command line. `yargs` puts non-option command line arguments into `argv._`:

```
gulp.task("config", function () {
  if (argv._.indexOf('ftp') >= 0 || argv.ftp) {
    console.log("Reading FTP settings...");
  }
  if (argv._.indexOf('sync') >= 0 || argv.sync) {
    console.log("Reading Sync settings...");
  }
});
```

However this will not work if `ftp` isn't explicitly invoked on the command line. This could happen if `ftp` itself is executed because another task depends on it.

Comment: Thanks much! This has got me on the right path, will accept as soon as I nail it down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with refactoring:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

function config(type) {
    "use strict";
    if (type == 'ftp') {
        console.log("Reading FTP settings...");
    } else if (type == 'sync') {
        console.log("Reading Sync settings...");
    }   
}

gulp.task("config-ftp", function () {
    config('ftp');
});

gulp.task("config-sync", function () {
    config('sync');
});

gulp.task("ftp", ["config-ftp"], function(cb) {
    console.log("FTPing...");
});

gulp.task("sync", ["config-sync"], function(cb) {
    console.log("Syncing...");
});
```

Comment: That's how I've done it in the past, but I'm trying to consolidate my configuration tasks in to one. Thanks for the input.